# Add notification bar below navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I would like to add to my app a notification bar like the stackoverflow or Facebook app.

Basically to inform the user that the app is offline. What is the mechanism behind it? Mostly I am using uitableviews

[image]

Comment: Use  viewForHeaderInSection method of tableview for information view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do this:

1. Create a custom `UIView` with position as (0, 0) so it gets placed right under your navigation bar.
2. Add this as subView to your viewcontroller' view .
3. Adjust your tableView' Y position to move down.

You can also do it via adding retuning a custom UIView from `viewForHeaderInSection:` method of tableViewController but then it will scroll along with the table.